# DTL не обрабатывает переменную

Tags: django, шаблоны

В общем ситуация следующая: при `{{ 231nevedomaЯdich)03%sd.e2123as }}` сервер отдаёт логичное исключение. То есть переменная вроде и обрабатывается, но всё же при правильном значении переменной страница всё равно не отдаёт атрибуты объекта. Также, если я напишу валидное название переменной, но не ту, что принадлежит объекту, он всё равно выводит пустую страницу, а не исключение.

[image: Переменная принадлежащая нужной модели]
[image: S даёт увидеть что у модели есть два объекта и цикл их перебиравет]

Comment: Смею предположить, что я где-то заспойлил код templates/defaulttags.py поэтому я попробую переустановить сам фреймворк. Но собираюсь ставить 2.0. Так что решения проблемы, я решил избежать. Вопрос можно считать закрытым.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поставил django2.0a1, чтоб сразу привыкать к нему. Проблема решилась, скорее всего я всё-таки заспойлил код самой джанги. Сейчас всё норм обрабатывается.